# Find limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^4}{k^5+n^5}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation, riemann-sum

Find the following limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^4}{k^5+n^5}$$
I had an idea of using upper Riemann sum for function $x^4$ on interval $[0,1]$ but I don't know how to deal with $k^5$ in denominator which ruins my approach. Kindly asking for some help.

Comment: Maybe expand terms and see if anything cancels? Also please add some context for the problem.

Comment: Surely you can put this in the form $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n)$. Divide numerator and denominator by $n^5$.

Comment: $\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{n^4}{n^5+k^5}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{\big(\tfrac{k}{n}\big)^4}{1+\big(\tfrac{k}{n}\big)^5}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^1_0\frac{x^4}{1+x^5}\,dx$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using 'Definite integrals as limit of a sum':

The above limit is equivalent to $$\int_0^1{\frac{x^4}{x^5+1}}dx.$$

Substituting $z=x^5$ gives us $$\int_0^1{\frac{1}{5(z+1)}}dz$$
which is equal to $\displaystyle\frac{\log{2}}{5}$.